# Pandas - get first occurrence of a given column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` with repeated `names` for different rounds of a tournament, like so:

```
name   round_id price_open
John       1     5.0
Paul       1     4.0
John       2     5.4
Paul       2     3.4
John       3     5.0
Paul       3     4.0
```

But at round 3, a new player enters the tournament:

```
...
George     3     6.0
...
```

---

Lets say I need to filter down all starting prices, like so:

```
df_open = df[df['round_id']==1]['price_open']
```

This will get `NaN` for George, which is not what I need.

---

So how do I filter this df in order to get first opening prices for all players, ending up with?

```
name  price_open
John   5.0
Paul   4.0
George 6.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` to keep the first instance of each name:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('name')
     name  round_id  price_open
0    John         1         5.0
1    Paul         1         4.0
6  George         3         6.0
```

Comment: should I not specify keep first or keep last?

Comment: By default `keep='first'`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the index of the first occurrence by each name present in your dataframe using [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), then you can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) method to get the correct rows:

**Using list-comprehension:**

```
df.iloc[[df.name.eq(name).idxmax() for name in df['name'].value_counts().index]]
```

**Without list-comprehension:**

```
indexes = []
for name in df['name'].value_counts().index:
  indexes.append(df.name.eq(name).idxmax())
df.iloc[indexes]
```

Output:

|  | name | round_id | price_open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | 1 | 4.0 |
| 0 | John | 1 | 5.0 |
| 6 | George | 3 | 6.0 |

**[EDIT]:** I have no idea about the parameters accepted by [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) method, it is better use it if it resolves your requirement :).